# How to return more than one value from a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, multiple-variable-return

How to return more than one variable from a function in Python?

Answer (score 160):

You separate the values you want to return by commas:

```
def get_name():
   # you code
   return first_name, last_name
```

The commas indicate it's a tuple, so you could wrap your values by parentheses:

```
return (first_name, last_name)
```

Then when you call the function you a) save all values to one variable as a tuple, or b) separate your variable names by commas

```
name = get_name() # this is a tuple
first_name, last_name = get_name()
(first_name, last_name) = get_name() # You can put parentheses, but I find it ugly
```

Comment: Your answer is much more clear, more concise, and easier to understand than several answers I have seen for similar questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Here is also the code to handle the result:

```
def foo (a):
    x=a
    y=a*2
    return (x,y)

(x,y) = foo(50)
```

Comment: This one is even better than from NXC, because it shows how to call it.

Answer (score 6):

Return as a tuple, e.g.

```
def foo (a):
    x=a
    y=a*2
    return (x,y)
```