# Is it possible for a python function to return more than 1 value?

Tags: python, function, return-value

I am learning the use of functions in python and want to know if it is possible to return more than 1 value.

Comment: @Ignacio: True, you can't. But, doesn't returning a tuple serve the purpose?

Comment: @dheerosaur: Absolutely. But it's still 1 tuple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [return more than one value from a function in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423710/return-more-than-one-value-from-a-function-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python has some parameter unpacking which is cool. So although you can only return one value, if it is a tuple, you can unpack it automatically:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return 1, 2, 3, 4 # Returns a tuple
>>> foo()
(1, 2, 3, 4)

>>> a, b, c, d = foo()
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
>>> d
4
```

In Python 3 you have more advanced features:

```
>>> a, *b = foo()
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3, 4]
>>> *a, b = foo()
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
4
>>> a, *b, c = foo()
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3]
>>> c
4
```

But that doesn't work in Python 2.

Answer (score 7):

You can return the values you want to return as a tuple.

Example:

```
>>> def f():
...     return 1, 2, 3
... 
>>> a, b, c = f()
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
>>>
```

Comment: You can drop the parentheses in the return statement, as Python converts a statement like `return 1,2,3` to `return (1,2,3)` automatically. Pro: you save to characters and it improves readability a bit

Comment: @Martin: Yes, that's true. Just want to note that `print` and `return` are both statements in Python2, but print converts each expression to an object and prints where as return evaluates the expression list and returns (which totally makes sense for return).

Answer (score 1):

```
def two_values():
    return (1, 2)

(a, b) = two_values()
```

Comment: +1 to counter unexplained, unjustified downvote (yes, the parens are not necessary, but that's not a downvotable offense).

Comment: I dislike omitting the parens. The cost in readability doesn't justify the two characters you save. I suppose you could argue that it improves readability in this context, since you are thinking, "return two values," instead of, "return a tuple," but frankly you *are* returning a tuple, and I prefer to say what I mean than to pretend something else is happening.

Comment: A tuple is created by the commas, not by the parentheses. In this case the parentheses are completely redundant.

Comment: @Duncan: When I call `f(1, 2)`, the comma does not create a tuple, the extra parentheses in `f((1, 2))` do. Yes, I know that technically (in the grammar) the commas denote the tuple, while the parentheses simply suppress the alternate parse, but knowing that doesn't make it any less confusing.

Comment: @Duncan: I just thought of a better example. What do you think `two_values = lambda: 1, 2` will do?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: I think it will create a tuple with two values (the first of which is a function). Why? What do you think it will do?

Comment: @Duncan: You obviously missed my point (intentionally, perhaps?). `def two_values(): return 1, 2` and `two_values = lambda: 1, 2` have very similar syntactic structure, but one defines a function that returns a tuple, while the other creates a tuple containing a function. Wrapping parentheses around `1, 2` in both cases eliminates the inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
def f():
   return 1, 2


x, y = f()
# 1, 2
```